# Why does my farkle game not finish playing the round, and gives a random score number

Tags: c++, loops, scoring

I'm creating this farkle game as a final project for class. The game runs the first time then as you're asking to save the dice one at a time it stops after 3, and prints out a large random negative number. Then jump's to the next player's turn but doesn't display their name.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



using namespace std;

int diceGame()
{
int dice[6], roll, keep[6], score;
char answer, done;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    dice[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << "You rolled " << (i + 1) << ". " << dice[i] << endl;
    roll = dice[i];
}

    for (int i = 0; i < dice[i]; i++)
    {

        cout << "Do you want to keep dice #" << (i + 1) << "? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
        {
            keep[i] = dice[i];
        }

        if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[1] == 1 && keep[2] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[1] == 1 && keep[3] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[1] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[1] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[3] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[4] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[3] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[2] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[4] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[2] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[4] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[2] == 1 && keep[3] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[2] == 1 && keep[4] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[3] == 1 && keep[4] == 1 && keep[5] == 1)
        {
            score = score + 1000;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 1 && keep[1] != 1 && keep[2] != 1 && keep[3] != 1 && keep[4] != 1 && keep[5] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 1 && keep[0] != 1 && keep[2] != 1 && keep[3] != 1 && keep[4] != 1 && keep[5] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[2] == 1 && keep[1] != 1 && keep[0] != 1 && keep[3] != 1 && keep[4] != 1 && keep[5] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[3] == 1 && keep[1] != 1 && keep[2] != 1 && keep[0] != 1 && keep[4] != 1 && keep[5] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[4] == 1 && keep[1] != 1 && keep[2] != 1 && keep[3] != 1 && keep[0] != 1 && keep[5] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[5] == 1 && keep[1] != 1 && keep[2] != 1 && keep[3] != 1 && keep[4] != 1 && keep[0] != 1)
        {
            score = score + 100;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == 5 && keep[1] != 5 && keep[2] != 5 && keep[3] != 5 && keep[4] != 5 && keep[5] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[1] == 5 && keep[0] != 5 && keep[2] != 5 && keep[3] != 5 && keep[4] != 5 && keep[5] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[2] == 5 && keep[1] != 5 && keep[0] != 5 && keep[3] != 5 && keep[4] != 5 && keep[5] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[3] == 5 && keep[1] != 5 && keep[2] != 5 && keep[0] != 5 && keep[4] != 5 && keep[5] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[4] == 5 && keep[1] != 5 && keep[2] != 5 && keep[3] != 5 && keep[0] != 5 && keep[5] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[5] == 5 && keep[1] != 5 && keep[2] != 5 && keep[3] != 5 && keep[4] != 5 && keep[0] != 5)
        {
            score = score + 50;
        }
        else if (keep[0] == keep[1] && keep[2] || keep[0] == keep[1] && keep[3] || keep[0] == keep[1] && keep[4] || keep[0] == keep[1] && keep[5])
        {
            score = score + (keep[0] * 100);
        }
        else if (keep[1] == keep[2] && keep[3] || keep[1] == keep[2] && keep[4] || keep[1] == keep[2] && keep[5])
        {
            score = score + (keep[1] * 100);
        }
        else if (keep[2] == keep[3] && keep[4] || keep[2] == keep[3] && keep[5])
        {
            score = score + (keep[2] * 100);
        }
        else if (keep[3] == keep[4] && keep[5])
        {
            score = score + (keep[3] * 100);
        }


        cout << "Are you done this round? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> done;

        if (done == 'y' || done == 'Y')
        {
            break;
        }

}


return score;
}



int main()
{
int playerNum, score;
char rulesAnswer, doneAnswer;
string line;


srand(time(NULL));

cout << "Welcome to FARKLE!!!" << endl;
cout << "Coded by: " << endl;
cout << endl;


do {
    cout << "Would you like to read the rules? (Y or N)" << endl; //rules option
    cin >> rulesAnswer;
    if (rulesAnswer == 'Y' || rulesAnswer == 'y')
    {
        ifstream ruleFile("farkleRules.txt"); //call file to be opened
        if (ruleFile.is_open()) //if loop to check if the file is open
        {
            while (getline(ruleFile, line)) //while the file is open read line by line
            {
                cout << line << endl; //display the file
            }
            ruleFile.close(); // close the file
            break;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Unable to open the file" << endl;; //error warning if the file fails to open
        }
    }
    else if (rulesAnswer == 'N' || rulesAnswer == 'n')
    {
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter Y or N only" << endl; //answer requirement
    }

} while (rulesAnswer != 'Y' || rulesAnswer != 'y');

do {
    cout << "How many players?" << endl; //getting numer of players
    cin >> playerNum;

    if (playerNum < 2) { //player requirement
        cout << "Please add more players." << endl;
    }

} while (playerNum < 2);

vector<string> playerName(playerNum);
ofstream ruleFile;



for (int i = 0; i < playerNum; i++) //for loop to get name of all the players
{
    cout << "Player " << i + 1 << " name?" << endl;
    cin >> playerName[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < playerNum; i++)
{
    cout << playerName[i] << "'s turn." << endl;
    do
    {
        score = diceGame();
        cout << playerName[i] << "'s score is: " << score << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to stop playing?" << endl;
        cin >> doneAnswer;

        if (doneAnswer == 'Y' || doneAnswer == 'y')
        {
            break;
        }



    } while (doneAnswer != 'Y' || doneAnswer != 'y');
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code while it is executing using a debugger?

Comment: blind guess: uninitialized variables. Btw, you just lost your anonymity by posting your full name ;) (unless its a fake name)

Comment: There are [multiple *very* impactful warnings in this code](https://pastebin.com/FV6mKJ8e). I suggest you enable all your warnings to pedantic levels and fix them; not hide them.